# How to clone and make multiple replacements

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, clone

Here is my JS, I am cloning the div `#product-1`, the new clone has currently got the label changed, I was wondering how to make additional replacements.

```
var clone = $('#product-1').clone(false);
clone.find(".ingredientLabel").html(clone.find(".ingredientLabel").html().replace(/[0-9]+/g, counter));
$(clone).appendTo(".activeingredients");
```

How can I change the id from `product-1` to `'product-'+counter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to change the ID attribute before transversing down into the cloned dom element with `find()`

```
clone.attr('id', 'product-'+counter).find(".ingredientLabel").html(clone.find(".ingredientLabel").html().replace(/[0-9]+/g, counter));
```

Once you use find(), `.ingredientLabel` becomes the selected object you are chaining methods to.

Chain methods to `clone` to select `#product-1` before selecting `.ingredientLabel`